# How to search active directory with PrincipalSearchResult excluding certain OUs in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am searching for user accounts in active directory with this code, which works just fine.

```
Dim insPrincipalContext As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName, "DC=domain,DC=com")

    Dim insUserPrincipal As New UserPrincipal(insPrincipalContext)
    insUserPrincipal.Description = empID
    Dim insPrincipalSearcher As New PrincipalSearcher()
    Dim currentADUser As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal
    insPrincipalSearcher.QueryFilter = insUserPrincipal
    Dim results As PrincipalSearchResult(Of Principal) = insPrincipalSearcher.FindAll
    For Each p As Principal In results
        currentADUser = p
        adUsername = currentADUser.SamAccountName
        adLast = currentADUser.Surname
        adFirst = currentADUser.GivenName
        adMail = currentADUser.EmailAddress
    Next
```

The problem is that the user account I want could be in several places, so I don't want to specify an OU to search, but it could be in 2 OUs that I do not want it to be returned from. Is there a way to exclude these 2 OUs from my search?

I have found some similar questions but none that were using VB.Net and the system.directory.accountmanagement  namespace in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do what I want by adding DistinguishedName to my results and checking it for the OU's I want to exclude. Here is the fully working example.

```
Dim insPrincipalContext As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName, "DC=Mydomain,DC=com")

    Dim insUserPrincipal As New UserPrincipal(insPrincipalContext)
    insUserPrincipal.Description = empID
    Dim insPrincipalSearcher As New PrincipalSearcher()
    Dim currentADUser As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal
    insPrincipalSearcher.QueryFilter = insUserPrincipal
    Dim results As PrincipalSearchResult(Of Principal) = insPrincipalSearcher.FindAll
    For Each p As Principal In results
        currentADUser = p
        adDistName = currentADUser.DistinguishedName
        If InStr(adDistName, "OU=UnwantedOU1") Or InStr(adDistName, "OU=UnwantedOU2") Then
            Continue For
        Else
            adUsername = currentADUser.SamAccountName
            adLast = currentADUser.Surname
            adFirst = currentADUser.GivenName
            adMail = currentADUser.EmailAddress
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim reduce = results.Where(Function(p) p.SamAccounNams = "Name").FirstOrDefault
```

okay then do it this way

```
Dim reduce results.Where(Function(p) Not p.DistinguishedName.Contains("OU=UnwantedOU1") and Not p.DistinguishedName.Contains("OU=UnwantedOU").ToList()
```

This will give you all the users not in the two unwanted OUs.

Good Luck

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit on what that code is doing and how it fits into my code? I'm a bit new to vb.net. I do only want one result, but it won't necessarily be the first result if I can't specify OUs to exclude.

Comment: Since your results could have multiple values I used the Linq Where to filter for a specific name then use FirstOrDefault to return the first value if there is one or more in the results.

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps limit the result by OU though. Am I missing something or are you maybe not fully understanding what I'm trying to do? I appreciate your input regardless.

Comment: It is also possible that the user only has one account and it's in one of the OUs I don't want to search, in which case I do not want any result to be returned.

Comment: Check out my revision.  Let me know if you need more clarification.